# what does this git icon mean in nerd fonts?

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using ohmyzsh and installed git plugin and nerd-font. Trying to understand the meaning of this
[image]

Also would be great, if I can find some table with the meanings of symbols.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That icon means [you have one stash](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k#vcs)

Answer (score 4):

that is the number of stashes you have:

here the official table with all symbols:

[image]

or the url to the official doc:

https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k#vcs